# Как добавить фразу в массив как один элемент с помощью split?

Tags: javascript, массивы, split

У меня есть строка, которую я превращаю в массив с помощью `split(" ")`.
Например:

```
apple orange pineaple
["apple", "orange", "pineaple"]
```

Но как я могу добавить два слова в один элемент, чтобы было вот так?

```
apple orange pineaple "green banana"
["apple", "orange", "pineaple", "green banana"]
```

Спасибо!

Comment: split может принимать регулярное выражение

Comment: Не совсем понимаю. Можете помочь?

Comment: как именно ты отделяешь слова, которые должны быть в одном элементе?

Comment: скобками, как в примере. "green banana"

Comment: скобками - это кавычками?

Comment: да, перепутал.  кавычками вот такими " "

Comment: например: `'apple orange pineaple "green banana"'.match(/\w+|"([^"]+)"/g)`

Comment: А откуда прилетает строка? Если собирается каким-то циклом, можно ведь вместо пробелов использовать другой разделитель) Например `"apple|orange|pineaple|green banana".split("|")`

Comment: Технически у меня разделитель пробел и нужно чтоб из например такого add 2017-04-25 3 EUR “French fries” разделило на ["add" "2017-04-25" "3" "EUR" “French fries”]

Comment: Напоминает CSV. Попробуйте такое решение [CSVToArray](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1504-ask-ben-parsing-csv-strings-with-javascript-exec-regular-expression-command.htm). В песочнице проверил и вроде бы [работает](https://jsfiddle.net/fo0rd64t/) для вашего случая не плохо. Правда, есть нюанс - создается двумерный массив

Answer (score 0):

Вот собственно и велосипед.

```js
let text = '"add "2017-04-25 3 " qq"qqq EUR" "Sasha doesnt have" any " friends qqqqq" "qwe qwe qwe qwe"';
let arr = [];
let tempArr = text.split(' ');
for(i=0;i<tempArr.length;i++){//Начали бегать по массиву элементов текста
   if(tempArr[i][0]=='"'){//Проверка открывается ли ковычка
      let tempVar = tempArr[i]+' ';//Положили первый найденный объект после кавычки в переменную
      for(k=i+1;k<tempArr.length;k++){//Запустили цикл поиска закрывающей кавычки
        if(tempArr[k][tempArr[k].length-1]=='"'){//Проверка закрывается ли объект кавычкой
          tempVar+=(tempArr[k]);
          arr.push(tempVar);//Запихнули переменную в общий массив
          i+=k-i;
          break;//Прерываем вложеннный цикл
        }else{
          tempVar+=(tempArr[k]+' ');//Запихиваем промежуточные объекты между кавычками в перменную
          if(k==tempArr.length-1){//Если только одна кавычка
             arr.push(tempVar.split(' ')[0]);
          }
        }
      }
      if(i+1==tempArr.length&&tempVar.split(' ').length==1){
        arr.push(tempVar.split(' ')[0]);
      }
   }else{
      arr.push(tempArr[i]);
   }
}
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  $("#show").append(arr[i]+'</br>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='show'></div>
```

p.s В прошлых изменениях укороченная версия.

Comment: слишком пестрит количеством `text.split(' ')`

Comment: @Grundy, лень было запихивать в переменную.

Comment: а кучу раз копировать не лень было? :)

Comment: @Grundy, в этом то и дело, создавать переменную - 10-15 кликов по клаве(+придумать название, а это невыносимый мною труд!), скопировать - ctrl+C

Comment: стоит это поправить и добавить описание того, что происходит в коде. Плюс указать, что этот код только фразу из двух слов может обработать и `"French no fries"` попадет уже в три элемента, а не в один

Comment: @Grundy, можете посмотреть, как исправил, если интересно

Comment: если кавычка будет одна - то все что после нее идет - пропадет. text.split лучше вынести, сейчас их стало еще больше

Comment: @Grundy, Если я правильно понимаю, то в ответе должен быть не универсальный алгоритм с обработкой всевозможных исключений, а алгоритм предназначенный под конкретный пример. Так-то да, разумеется я с вами согласен, что при наличии лишь одной кавычки - все, что после нее - пропадает.

Comment: Я и не говорил про универсальность, я говорил - добавить описание где алгоритм перестает работать, и вынести `text.split` в переменную

Comment: @Grundy, видимо я вас не так понял. Но не пропадать же моим изменениям, хуже точно не станет.